# How to set rounded corner on rectangle node of scene graph

Tags: android, roku, brightscript

I am working on roku app and using rectangle node of scene graph. I want to set rounded corners on rectangle so please suggest me.

Xml code is:

```
<Rectangle
   id="showHide"
   color="#451bc1"
   visible="false"
   width="500"
   height="100"
   translation="[150,600]" />
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no way of doing this, you may create an image, which looks like rectangle you need, and use it with [Poster](https://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Poster) node.

Comment: #Does roku supports pause/resume functionality during video buffering? Im using ".m3u8" file format with video node.

Comment: videoNode.control = "pause"/"resume"

Comment: control = "pause" is not working during video buffering.

Answer (score 0):

RSG now supports 9 patch images, so you can create a small image with rounded corners and use Poster node to show it.
Also, you can use blend color to set color of this image

Comment: Whilst that might be true, it is not necessarily useful for the OP.

Comment: Shame about my downvote.  What I was trying to say is that it may not be possible for the OP to move to a newer version or use some third party package, so you should really try to provide a solution without having to do that.  If it's not possible then fair enough, and you can state as much in your comment.